# Show Image from JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, image, parsing

The JSON URL is http://api.bfhstats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=pc&name=1ApRiL&output=js

On line 16 It contains the part "imgLarge" which i'm trying to get to show the image on my website. When i parse the data to my website it is currently just showing the string, not an actual image.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
$("#playerstuff").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",

        url: 'http://api.bfhstats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=' + document.getElementById("platform").value +'&name=' + document.getElementById("playername").value,  
        //datatype : "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            document.getElementById("playerrank").innerHTML = 'gamingstats.ga/' +data["player"]["rank"].imgLarge;
                            $("#formpanel").hide();
                            $("#dataret").show();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The output of this is the URL which is gamingstats.ga/bfh/ranks/r57.png however not the actual image.

Comment: You need to make an `<img src='' />` tag and set the `src` to the image you want displayed.  Right now, you are just adding a string to your `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thank you, how would I go about doing this within PHP ?

Comment: Using string concatenation.  `$img = "<img src='".$url."' />";`

Comment: That's done the trick thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line ...

```
document.getElementById("playerrank").innerHTML = 'gamingstats.ga/' +data["player"]["rank"].imgLarge;
```

to ...

```
document.getElementById("playerrank").innerHTML = '<img src="http://gamingstats.ga/' +data["player"]["rank"].imgLarge + '" />';
```